# UI Automation: Access UIViews inside UIScrollView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, automation

Is there a way to access, using JavaScript with UI Automation tests, the `UIViews` inside an `UIScrollView`? Since the `UIScrollView` doesn't give me away to set if it has accessibility or not, I would like to know if it is possible to do that.

The structure in the XIB:

[image]

I can see everything on the instrument's log, except the `UIScrollView` and the `UIViews` inside of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to access the interior of my Scroll View. What I was doing wrong:

- Setting accessibility to my root view.
- Setting accessibility to my Adjusted view.

After removing that, I was able my doing this:

```
var window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow(); 
window.logElementTree();
```

To see all the UIViews inside my UIScrollView. To access one of the buttons:

```
 var scrollView = window.scrollViews()[0];
 var button=scrollView.buttons()["showMeStuff"];
 button.tap();
```

PS: Is also possible to define the accessibility of an UIScrollView by doing the following:

```
  scrollView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
  scrollView.accessibilityLabel = @"someScrollView";
```